# Hive sql avg table by subquery or join

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have two tables:

movies

```
movieid int                                         
title   string
```

ratings

```
userid    int                                       
movieid   int                                       
rating    float                                     
timestamp string
```

I want to get result like this

```
movietitle ratingavg
--------------------   
movie 1     4.8
movie 2      8
```

This is my query:

```
select avg(r.rating), m.title 
from ratings r 
join movies m on r.movieId = m.movieId;
```

and this

```
select m.title, (select avg(r.rating) from ratings r) 
from movies m 
join ratings r on r.movieId = m.movieId;
```

but I am getting an error:

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 1:21 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'title'

Comment: i also tried this.
select m.title,(select avg(r.rating) from ratings r) from movies m JOIN ratings r ON r.movieId = m.movieId;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT avg(r.rating)
    ,m.title
FROM ratings r
JOIN movies m ON r.movieId = m.movieId
GROUP BY m.title;
```